# Bootstrap search form wrapper alter

Tags: hooks, theming

I am using the 7.x-3.0 version of Bootstrap and have sub themed it. I want to change wrapped div, add 'input-group-sm' to the class bit I can't not figure out how to override it. if I add search-block-form.tpl.php to my sub theme I can access and alter that but the code I need is in bootstrap-search-form-wrapper-func.php I have copied that to my sub theme with no success. I have tried replicating the same file structure as Bootstrap 'mytheme/theme/bootstrap/bootstrap-search-form-wrapper.func.php', I have tried putting just in my templates dir.

My last attempt was trying to follow the instructions on theme registry alters: https://www.drupal.org/node/2224003 which I have as this:

```
function CFbootstrap_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks['CFbootstrap_hook'] = array(
    'CFbootstrap_search_form_wrapper' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );

  bootstrap_hook_theme_complete($existing, $theme, $path . '/theme');
  return $hooks;
}
```

Nothing works, what I am doing wrong? How do I override this *.func.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have this figured out, I think I just got confused by instructions and getting ramped up again on the ways of Drupal. Anyway just to leave a clear answer. All subthemes will be called *MYTHEME*. In my template.php in my subtheme I altered the form and then added hook to my new form wrapper:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'search_form':
            dpm($form);
            $form['basic']['keys']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('MYTHEME_search_form_wrapper');
            break;
    }
  }
}

function MYTHEME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = array(
      'MYTHEME_search_form_wrapper' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
      'file' => 'MYTHEME-search-form-wrapper.func.php',
    ),
  );

  return $hooks;
}
```

In this I copied the original wrapper file and made my changes, you could just copy the method and add it to your template.php anyway here's that method, referenced earlier as '*MYTHEME-search-form-wrapper.func.php*':

```
function MYTHEME_MYTHEME_search_form_wrapper($variables) {
  $output = '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">';
  $output .= $variables['element']['#children'];
  $output .= '<span class="input-group-btn">';
  $output .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">';
  // We can be sure that the font icons exist in CDN.
  if (theme_get_setting('bootstrap_cdn')) {
    $output .= _bootstrap_icon('search');
  }
  else {
    $output .= t('Search');
  }
  $output .= '</button>';
  $output .= '</span>';
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Key here is having the subtheme name twice in the method call. The instructions I found on this didn't give an explanation on why that needs to be. I'll try to find relevant information.

Comment: This works, but it only addresses the form on the search results page.  It does affect the search block, but I get two search buttons.

Comment: I suggest you mark your own answer as "accepted" (so that it is no longer considered as "unanswered").

Answer (score 0):

The array structure is wrong, since it should be the following.

```
  $hooks['CFbootstrap_search_form_wrapper'] = array(
    'render element' => 'element',
  );
```

What they show as `'theme_key'` doesn't mean `'<put here your theme short name>_key'` but `'<put here the theme function name>'`. See for example the [implementation of `hook_theme()` done from the Node module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_theme/7), which contains the following code.

```
 return array(
    'node' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'node',
    ),
    'node_search_admin' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),

    // …
  );
```

Notice also that calling `bootstrap_hook_theme_complete($existing, $theme, $path . '/theme')` is not anymore necessary with the Bootstrap theme 7.x-3.1.

Comment: `function CFbootstrap_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks['search_block_form'] = array (
      'render element' => 'form',
      'file' => 'theme/search/search-block-form.tpl.php',
  );
  
  $hooks['bootstrap_search_form_wrapper'] = array(
      'render element' => 'element',
      'file' => 'theme/bootstrap/bootstrap-search-form-wrapper.func.php',
  );

  bootstrap_hook_theme_complete($existing, $theme, $path . '/theme');
  return $hooks;
}
` This now pulls a different search form all together. Not the bootstrap or my sub theme? PS I'm on 7.x-3.0.

Comment: I have upgraded to 7.x-3.1-beta2 also removed my hook_theme function and just copied the files to my sub theme and used blocks. Using theme debugger I can see that it's using the form template I copied but it's still not using the func.php that I copied. Do I not understand this or is this a bug? Serious questions because I am at a loss with this.